# rewriterule image to php script and joomla not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, joomla, url-rewriting

I want to e able to serve some image whose content is based on a payment condition.
The image should be available on `http://example.com/banner/image_**code**.gif`
(code is different for every client.)

rewriterule should change that link to `index.php?option=com_joomlacomponent&img=**code**`

I wrote what I supposed to be a very simple rule to accomplish that but it doesn't work.

I added the rewriterule to an existing .htaccess in the document root.
The .htaccess contains rules to add the standard slash, www, to redirect old php files to new php files and to add to the path the name of the directory where there's the joomla install.

The structure of the file/folders is as follows:

```
/.htaccess
/cms/.htaccess (joomla standard .htaccess)
/cms/*  (joomla files)
```

I tried the following rules:

```
RewriteRule ^banner/image_(.*)\.gif$ index.php?option=com_joomlacompanent&
img=$1
```

I get the homepage of joomla (adding various flags didn't help, e.g. [L].)

I tried adding a rewritecond to check if the condition was satisfied:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /banners/image_(.*).gif$
RewriteRule . http://othersite.com/%1 [L]
```

and I get redirected to othersite/code where code is the code in the initial url.

So I wonder if I'm missing some important concept of rewriterule or if there's some interference between this rule and other rules or joomla .htaccess.

EDIT: I found out what the problem is.
I wrongly supposed that my php could temporarily serve a debug message (an echo) instead of a real image.
Probably joomla doesn't allow that redirecting to the homepage.

Now I'm using the following rule in the .htaccess in document root:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /banner/image_(.*).gif$
RewriteRule .* index.php?option=com_joomlacomponent&img=%1
```

And in the component php file:

```
$img = 'path to an img file';
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
readfile($img);
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication();
$mainframe->close();
exit;
```

I think the question can be flagged as Solved.

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you asking your future [tag:joomla]-related questions there.

Comment: To me it is not clear what you are attempting to do. Are you attempting to return a document of type gif? I mean if you know the value of code call it `$code` why not just go to that url?  `http://example.com/banner/image_' . $code . '.gif'`   Are you trying to download the file?   Why are you trying to rewrite at all?

Comment: @Elin I want to serve images customised for every user/client. I could do something like <img src="http://www.example.com/index.php?component=mycomp&img=customeruniquecode" /> but I thought it would be more user-friendly to use an image-like url instead of a php url. 
The image changes in time so there must be a check every time the image is served.
Rewriting didn't appear to me a difficult task, it works when using only one .htaccess
The problem is the "interference" with the joomla .htaccess.
Since there's no simple solution, I'll go with the php url.

Comment: When you say an "image-like url" do you mean one ending with gif in the rendered html? And this image is on another site? And you want to return a document that is only the image and not html with an image inside it, right? Joomla does have an image document type you might want to use for that.  If all you want to do is disguise the name you could look at how routing in weblinks works. Is the user-specific string coming from inside Joomla or coming from the other site when you make the request?

Comment: @elin I have to give to the customers the html code to show a banner where they want.
I just wanted to give them
<a href="http://www.example.com/clientitem" ><img src="http://example.com/banner/image_1a2bcf5e.gif" /></a>
instead of
<a href="http://www.example.com/clientitem" ><img src="http://example.com/.../index.php?option=com_joomlacomponent&img=1a2bcf5e" /></a>
Anyway I edited my question and added what I was doing wrong.
(I'm not sure I was right to add the solution there, I couldn't find an add answer button, I'm a little bit confused about the way logins and logouts are managed here.)

Comment: OH see if you explain what you want, it's much easier to help.  So if I can restate to make sure I understand, you want to be able to embed the image on a third party site using a human readable path.   They will already know the custom name of the image, is that right? Your "php url" is a little bit odd for joomla in that it doesn't have a view or a task.  Let me think about this, can you just confirm my understanding? Right now if you put in the "php url" are you getting what you want?

Comment: @elin Thank you for your help but I think I solved the problem. As I said it wasn't a rewriterule problem.
The php url I wrote about is only an example, I use chronoforms and urls are pretty long.
I'll give to each customer a unique image url. The url contains a unique customer code. I'll use rewriterule to pass that code to chronoforms.

Comment: Okay if you are now going to totally change the terms of the question (i.e. that is is about proper joomla URLs from chronoforms and not about a crazy url for a custom extension that you have written) it's not worth even trying to help.  I'd really suggest you read some of the "how to ask good quesitons" documentation and also speak with the chronoforms developers.

Comment: @elin I'm sorry, I wrote in my question what I was trying to accomplish, what was the error I found and the solution I used. As I already wrote the problem is now solved.

Answer (score 0):

Since your rules are in the htaccess file in your document root, don't you need to call into the cms folder?

```
RewriteRule ^banner/image_(.*)\.gif$ /cms/index.php?option=com_joomlacompanent&img=$1 [L]
```

Also note that you'll want that rule relatively close to the top (but below any rules that redirect).

Comment: That is one of the rules I tried, to no avail. I didn't list all of them in my question.
Anyway the last rule of my file was:
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cms/$1 [L]

Comment: @user32823 is there any other htacces files? like one in the banner folders?

Comment: There's no banner folder.

Comment: I also tried putting my rule near the top or near the end (before the cms rule) of the file. No way.